# PHP/MySQL - Calculate Total for each Reservation

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a Reservation application, and I'd like to calculate the total number of meals needed by reservations date span.

My database has fields:

```
$name - Person reserving
$chkin - Check in date (DATE yyyy-mm-dd)
$chkout - Check out date (DATE yyyy-mm-dd)
$guests - Number of people in group
$meal - Eating meals (Yes/No)
```

So for each reservation I have:

```
// Days of Stay
$days = (strtotime($chkout) - strtotime($chkin)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
```

What I'm not sure of is how to do the calculation for each reservation in the database.

My calculation for each reservation would be something like:

```
$days * $guests
```

I would appreciate advice on this query... I'm trying to give a snapshot of how many meals will be need to be prepared for a given month, weeekend, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MYSQL date diff to achieve a count of the days, then this can be multiplied by the number of guests. Finally you will need to select a date range for this search. Below are the basics or the MYSQL needed in order to get these values. This should put you on the right track to achieving what you want.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(a.chkout,a.chkin) * a.guests as meals
FROM table as a 
WHERE a.chkin > '0000-00-00' AND a.chkout < '0000-00-00
```

I have tested this with a table of mine and it appears to be working correctly, however, without much data I can only test lightly. If you have any issues, leave a comment and I will try to help further.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Comment: I was able to use your reply with the others to get a solution.. thx!

Comment: @bash3r not a problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:-

```
SELECT SUM(guests * DATEDIFF(IF(chkin < $start_range, $start_range, chkin), IF(chkout > $end_range, $end_range, chkout)))
FROM sometable
WHERE chkin < $end_range
AND chkout > $start_range
AND meal = 'Yes'
```

Uses DATEDIFF() to get the number of days between the check in date (or if later the start of the date range you are interested in) and the check out date (or if earlier the end of the date range you are interested in) where meal is 'yes' and multiplies that by the number of guests, then uses SUM() to add them up for all bookings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I used your reply along with Erik Nedwidek's to get a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a snippet as a starting point.

Let's say you want the top 10 guests with the longest stay.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(chkout, chkin) AS daysstaying FROM reservations ORDER BY daysstaying DESC LIMIT 10
```

You can do calculations in queries and use the AS operator to create an alias for the result. I'm leaving it to you to work out the specific query you need to obtain the results you need.

I would also suggest that you investigate using views if this query needs to be used often.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/views.html

Comment: Thanks Erik for your reply, I was able to use your's and Kickstart's to get a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Kickstart's and Erik's reply to come up with a solution! Thanks!!

```
// Get Current Month
$current_month = date('F');

// Current timestamp is assumed, so these find first and last day of THIS month
$start_range = date('Y-m-01'); // hard-coded '01' for first day
$end_range  = date('Y-m-t');

        $sql = "SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(a.chkout,a.chkin) * a.guests) AS meals
        FROM reservations AS a
        WHERE a.chkin > '$start_range' AND a.chkout < '$end_range' 
        AND meal = 'Yes' AND confirm = 'Yes'";
```

No I will work towards forecasting for upcoming months as well!

Comment: Do you want to ignore guests who book in before the end of the previous month but check out at some point in the current month?

Comment: Hmm... good question.  My goal is to get a snapshot of how many meals to provide for our guests. I would like to possibly add this information to my FullCalendar that will instead of looking at the $current_month it would look at the month I'm on in FullCalendar, which I have FullCalendar pulling my reservations in from my database. Yea Me!

Comment: Coping with chkin / out ranged that are partially in the date range you are interested in was something my solution copes with.

Comment: @Kickstart let me test out your code again, I could not get it to work in my previous attempt.. but now I'm a few days wiser!

Comment: No problem (I did make a minor correction, as I realised I had a < where I meant to have a > ). Might be worth putting a test table up on sqlfiddle so we can check it out.